# Running Flask in Pycharm but can't enter custom commands

Tags: flask, pycharm, command, click, command-line-interface

I decided I wanted to learn how to create an API using Flask. I use Pycharm and created a run configuration using the flask server preset so that I can easily start my flask server from within Pycharm.

When I click the little green run arrow, the server starts correctly and some debug messages are shown in the console. The only issue I experience is that I can't enter commands in this console. I need this because I created some custom commands using click but I can't enter them in the console.

I am relatively new to Pycharm and Flaks, is there a way to configure this so I can still easily run the flask server from within Pycharm while also allowing me to enter commands?

Comment: You can run commands in Pycharm terminal not console

Comment: You can run commands in Pycharm terminal not console

Comment: You can modify the run settings to specify which CMD parameters to pass.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The results [in this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bflask%5d%20%5bpycharm%5d%20is%3aq) should explain all the cases you need to run Flask with PyCharm.